# File permission (write)

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, permission-denied

Hello,
Once I got this code to work with out any erros, and it downloaded the file.
Now it gives me a permission error,
I don't get the acesscontrol pop up that window should show.
**Anyways,

How can I get this code to download my file?**

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFTPuser.Text, txtFTPpassword.Text);
byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(fullDownloaPath);//dnoces.dreamhost.com
FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(downloadTo);

FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(@"BUILTIN\Users", 
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

File.SetAccessControl(downloadTo, security);
try
{
    FileStream f = File.Create(downloadTo/*+@"\"+file*/);
    f.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    f.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: try running your application as an administrator

Comment: It still gives me the same error... "Access denied to path ... is denied." (& for @ShadowWizard, WinForms)

Comment: What exact line is giving the error? Change to `MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());` to see full error with stack trace.

Comment: http://imageupload.org/?d=424CC50D1 - error

Comment: The *Games* folder is a virtual shell folder.  Pick a real directory.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "vitural shell folder"(@HansPassant), but I have tried several more folders and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in the 'downloadTo' variable ? I'm a little confused by your code. Since you can perform a GetAccessControl() I assume it must contain your Folder. If it would be your file, it would fail because it doesn't exist yet.

but then your code continues with

```
FileStream f = File.Create(downloadTo/*+@"\"+file*/);
```

since you wrote the /* */ your 'file' variable is commented, which makes me assume downloadTo than must contain the full path including the filename.

can you try and hardcode your destination file ?

(e.g. FileStream f = File.Create(@"c:\\users\\*your user*\\myfile.bin");

As far as I can interpret your code you're trying to write to Folder as such without specifying a filename.

Comment: Thanks but I figured it.(This is what I did).